# Postgis query to convert UTM to Lat long

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system

I want Postgres/PostGIS queries to convert UTM coordinates from UTM 43N projection to Decimal Degrees 32643 projection.

```
select ST_X(the_geom), ST_X(the_geom) from table
```

Comment: ST_Transform is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html). For example, taking a point somewhere in Southern India (which I'm guessing from the UTM zone and your profile is the area you are interesting in)

```
SELECT ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom) 
FROM 
(SELECT  ST_Transform(ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(627516, 1413990), 32643), 4326) as geom) g;
```

or in your case, if you have a table already with coordinates in:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ST_X(the_geom), ST_Y(the_geom)
FROM
(SELECT col1, col2, ST_Transform(the_geom, 4326) as the_geom from sometable) g;
```

If you don't have your geometry column's SRID set to 32643, you can either wrap this in ST_SetSRID, as in the first example, or run [UpdateGeometrySRID](http://postgis.org/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html) first to put your table's geometry column in the correct projection -- good practice anyway, to have this explicitly set.

Comment: Thanks John!!. If i want to display one more column from the table in the above query then please share the query.

Comment: You just select them in the subquery and then in the outer query. Post updated.

Comment: Possibly, can you ask a new question?